book_instance: Book = Book(Book.csv) AttributeError: type object 'Book' has no attribute 'csv'
I am trying to create a vector database using Python. I have this dataset in a CSV file:
Title,Author,Publisher
R for Data Science,Wickham and Grolemund,O'Reilly
Handbook of Mathematics for Engineers and Scientists,Polyanin Manzhirov,CRC
How to Think Like a Mathematician,Kevin Houston,Cambridge
The Study Skills Handbook,Stella Cortell,Palgrave Macmillan
Computer Security Principles and Practice,Stallings Brown,Pearson
Data Structures and Algorithms in Python,Goodrich Tammassa Godwasser
Essential Computer Mathematucs,Seymour Lipschutz,Schaums Outlines
Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists,Akritas,Pearson

# Import relevant libraries.
#from jina.types.document.generators import from_csv
from docarray import BaseDoc, DocList
import pandas as pd
from docarray.typing import TextUrl
from docarray.utils.filter import filter_docs
from pydantic import BaseModel, HttpUrl, validator


# Define the document schema describing the data:
class Book(BaseDoc):
    Title: str
    Author: str
    Publisher: str

book_data = {
    "title": "Essential Computer Mathematics",
    "Author": "Seymour Lipschutz",
    "Publisher": "Schaum's Outline",
}

book_instance: Book = Book(Book.csv)


# Load the content of the CSV file to a DocList instance of
# Books via .from_csv():
docs = DocList[Book].from_csv(
    file_path='C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\vector_database_using_vectordb\\Book.csv'
)

class BookReview(BaseDoc):
    Book: Book
    Title: str
    Author: str
    Publisher: str





review_docs = DocList[BookReview](
    [BookReview(book=Book, Title="Essential Computer Mathematics", Author="Seymour Lipschutz", Publisher="Schaum's Outlines") for Book in docs]
)
review_docs.summary()

docs.summary()

when I execute the code I am getting the following error:
AttributeError: type object 'Book' has no attribute 'csv'

How can I solve this problem?

I think you should remove .csv from book_instance: Book = Book(Book.csv)

When I remove .csv from book_instance: Book = Book(Book.csv), I get the following error: File "pydantic\main.py", line 332, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.init
TypeError: init() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

The reason for adding . csv to book_instance: Book = Book(Book.csv) is I was following this tutorial: https://docs.docarray.org/data_types/text/text/.
